# IOException when running wget command in java

Tags: java, wget

When I run wget command an `IOException` is thrown which says `No such File or Directory`.

And I guarantee that the command is correct and I tried it using terminal.

Here is my code.

```
default int execute(String[] command, StdOutLogger logger) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder()
            .command(command)
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    Process process = builder.start();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    bufferedReader.lines().forEach(logger::log);
    return process.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: Where are you using `wget` here?

Comment: You should include the full exception, or at least indicate in which line the exception happens.

Comment: Why use wget?  Why not use [HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)?  (Bonus: doing so makes your code multi-platform.)  And as of Java 11, you can use [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html).

Comment: `new File(System.getProperty("user.home"))` => No such File or Directory